# Send unauthenticated Google SMTP message using Zend_Mail

Tags: php, zend-framework, smtp, gmail, google-apps

I am trying to write a PHP script for a live production server to check if the IP whitelisting for the open SMTP relay settings on a Google account works properly.

Since the server is currently live I don't want to change any of the /etc/postfix/main.cf settings for the existing email solution, and thought I would try to write an isolated Zend_Mail script that could test it independently, but I'm having difficulties getting Zend_Mail to acknowledge an SMTP connection without login credentials.

I've tried different variations on

```
$domain = 'foo.bar.com';
$config = array('ssl' => 'tls', 'username' => 'noreply@bar.com');
$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp($domain, $config);

Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($transport);

$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setBodyText('This is the text of the mail.');
$mail->setFrom('noreply@bar.com', 'NoReply');
$mail->addTo('jono@gmail.com', 'jono');
$mail->setSubject('TestSubject');
$mail->send();
```

but it only times out, and I can't find any config options that would help.

So the question is, is it possible to send mail using Zend_Mail through a Google SMTP relay without using any login credentials, if the IP is whitelisted in the Gmail settings? If not, is there any other way to do this through the command line or another PHP library?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your $config array like this :

```
$config = array('ssl' => 'tls', 'port' => 587, 'auth' => 'login', 'username' => 'noreply@bar.com', 'password' => 'password');
$smtpConnection = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);
```

Comment: Did you keep the 'smtp.gmail.com' on the " new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com',$config); " line ? If not, keep it like this, do not put your domain instead.